# Split and concat values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, datareader

I have this csv file with very odd data format. The months are separated in columns with 1 and 0 as true or false and the days of job are in onde single string separated by commas.

I need to chage this to a normal date type, like "day/month" so i can do some analysis.

[image]

I tried to use pandas with melt method to separate columns

```
dfs.melt(id_vars=['ID_INVENTORY','JOBISN','DAYS_JOB'], value_vars=['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DECE'])
```

after that i got this result

[image]

But as pandas have no split method i don't really know what to do with that, but i fell i'm on the right path xD

Sample data below (separated by ";")

```
JAN;FEB;MAR;APR;MAY;JUN;JUL;AUG;SEP;OCT;NOV;DECE;DAYS_JOB
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
```

Comment: `df.DAYS_JOB.str.split(',', expand=True)` might help

Comment: From my understanding, you want to transform one line to multiple lines?

Comment: Yes take each day and turn it into a new line

Comment: It would help if you would provide a sample of how you expect the output dataframe to look rather than just describing it

Comment: Something like this:

ID_INVENTORY;ID_CTRLM_JOB;DAY/MONTH
1044;1;01/jan
1044;1;02/jan
1044;1;03/jan
1044;1;04/jan
1044;1;05/jan
1044;1;06/jan
1044;1;07/jan
1044;1;08/jan
1044;1;09/jan
1044;1;10/jan
1044;1;11/jan
1044;1;12/jan
1044;1;13/jan
1044;1;14/jan
1044;1;15/jan
1044;1;16/jan
1044;1;17/jan
1044;1;18/jan
1044;1;01/fev

Answer (score 1):

I assume the 1,2,3,4.... in column 'DAYS_JOB' is in string format.

In such case we can first split the string by comma, transform to list, and then use pandas explode function to expand the list item into multiple records. [[df.explode doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas.DataFrame.explode)]

The code will look like:

```
df['DAYS_JOB'] = df['DAYS_JOB'].apply(lambda x: list(x.split(",")))
df = df.explode('DAYS_JOB')
```

Comment: @FZs Thanks for the advice! I've updated the answer.